# Logged in members - account sharing

Tags: members, login, sessions, cookies, member-management

Is there a way to see whether a currently logged in user account is being used on more than one machine concurrently? I'm trying to find out whether users are sharing their usernames/passwords, as I manage a site that requires payment to access certain content.

I'm using the cookies only user session type. I have looked at using the 'Allow multiple log-ins from a single account?' option to prevent sharing but this caused issues when genuine users tried to access the site using multiple devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the `exp_sessions` table, where you can see both the `ip_address` and `member_id` for each session. Multiple sessions from wildly different IPs would be a cue that an account was being shared widely.